# C# UrlEncode but allow certain character sets

Tags: c#, unicode, urlencode

I have an application where users can upload files whose name can contain non-latin characters such as Cyrillic or Chinese. For example:

```
http://localhost/привет мир.html
```

I then need to be able to URL-encode the file name for illegal and/or special characters such as spaces. When I URL-encode a URI as follows:

```
string uri = "http://localhost/привет мир.html";
string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(uri);
Console.WriteLine(encoded);
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
http://localhost/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%20%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80.html
```

What I really want is this:

```
http://localhost/привет%20мир.html
```

Most browsers support this format and my users, who in this case are Russian, need to be able to see a more display-friendly URL in their language and character set.

Is there a way to URL-Encode a URI and have it not encode certain character sets?

Comment: Have you tried the `UrlEncode(string str, Encoding e)` overload with a specific encoding?

Comment: @SimonMourier - That will not do anything. The encoding used is already a Unicode one.

Comment: Problem is that URL Encoding means that everything on the URL is ASCII... and of course Cyrillic characters are not. You may need to write your own URL encoding routine.

Comment: I was hoping for something OOB, but I had a feeling I was going to have to write my own.  Thanks for the info everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create your own `HttpEncoder`.

[HttpEncoder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.aspx) - The **Remarks** section explain how to setup your website to use your `HttpEncoder` by default in the `HttpUtility`, `HttpServerUtility`, and `HttpResponseHeader`.